# Doctype information getting generated twice in output xml

Tags: xml, xslt

Following is a code snippet from my xsl file:

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">    
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>



    <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!DOCTYPE 
                topic [&#10;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!ENTITY 
                % textents PUBLIC "-//ENTITIES Project Text//en_US" 
                "text.ent">&#10;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">%textents;&#10;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">%idsents;&#10;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]>&#10;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:template>
```

The problem is that doctype information is getting generated twice in the output. Any suggestions as to how can I add the doctype information while retaining the identity transform?

Comment: Do you also have some `xsl:output` creating a DOCTYPE?

Comment: My xsl:output is: <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"
  encoding="UTF-8" />    If I remove the doctype code in original question, no doctype information is generated.

Comment: You might want to post a minimal but complete XSLT sample and input together with information of the used XSLT processor to allow us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have tried to create a minimal sample at http://xsltransform.net/ncdD7ns and don't see any duplicated DOCTYPE.

Comment: Well this is confusing me. When I am running the xslt using eclipse, doctype is repeated in the output but the rest of my code works fine. But I tried to run the same xslt using Java program, and also in the editor you mentioned, and it looks like the doctype output is correct but the rest of my xslt has not worked at all.

Comment: I don't know about Eclipse I am afraid, so you will need to wait for others to help clarify that. I would suggest you tag your question for Eclipse and provide precise information about the version and the plugin you use.